# pdb interactive mode throught telnet and rdb

Tags: python, debugging, telnet

I'm debugging a python daemon on a embedded Linux board.
I `ssh` to the board on which I run the program and enter the
debugger. Given that it's a deamon process I'm using `rdb` from `celery`

```
#Install on the system
pip3 install celery

# Set in the code
from celery.contrib import rdb
rdb.set_trace()

# Connect to the debugger
telnet localhost 5899
```

However in that session the `tab` key doesn't result in auto completion as usually in `pdb` and the `up` key doesn't scroll through history but prints a `^[[A`.

The issues like these are related to the missing `readline` python module, however in this particular case the module is present and can be imported.

Comment: @DaviLima, I believe you should use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9809574/2830850

Comment: @TarunLalwani, thanks, it sounds good but unfortunately it doesn't work  inside a Docker container: `rlwrap: error: My terminal reports width=0 (is it emacs?)  I can't handle this, sorry!`

Comment: @DaviLima, can you run `stty rows 50 && stty cols 150` in your terminal before running the `rlwrap` command see if that helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani, thanks, that solves with the arrows! Lastly, tab is still missing, though. Now nothing gets outputted when I press it, but it doesn't autocomplete either. Would you have any other hint?

Comment: It looks like it's possible to enable TABs but more complicated than one would enjoy. Answer by @HansLub, rlwrap's author: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9219349/462849 Plus, I couldn't find a Python/pdb/pdbpp/rdb example. If anyone knows of one, it'd be very welcome, maybe we could even repackage it with the stty+rlwrap+nc commands as an one step solution...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the issue is, and might be telnet related.
A workaround it to use another remote debugger that seems to work:

```
#Install on the system
pip3 install epdb

# Set in the code
import epdb; epdb.serve()

# Connect to the debugger
python3 -c 'import epdb; epdb.connect()'
```

Given that this is just a workaround, won't accept it as an answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! My connection to the debugger closes after 60 seconds, saying (Epdb) *** Connection closed by remote host ***. Any tips to extend the connection?

Comment: Ok, for anyone having connection timeout, it can be solved by adding   `--soft-time-limit 9999999` on your celery command.

Answer (score 3):

So your possible options are

**rlwrap**

```
rlwrap telnet host port
```

if you have col and rows issue run below

```
stty rows 50 && stty cols 150
```

**socat**

```
socat readline tcp:127.0.0.1:6900
```

This will add readline and history support without needing anything else like a `rlwrap`

I couldn't find a way as of yet to enable Telnet with tab completion. There are few interesting SO threads which talk about putting telnet client in a `nolinemode` or `charactermode`

[Force telnet client into character mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273261/force-telnet-client-into-character-mode)

I tried updating Rdb code to implement but all attempts failed as such

PS: Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9809574/2830850 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9219349/462849

Comment: `socat readline tcp:127.0.0.1:6900` fails with `socat[177] E unknown device/address "readline"` even if I run `stty` first and prefix it with `rlwrap` as suggested in https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole/issues/7#issuecomment-340092424 Running a Docker container with `Linux version 4.4.0-1052-aws (buildd@lgw01-amd64-031) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) )`

Comment: You need to have readline libraries installed inside the docker container